# Python - Scapy raw hexadecimal view

Tags: python, scapy, hexdump

I building a sniffer and I want to take the data from the `Raw` layer of a packet and show it as hexdump in a `wx.TextCtrl`. let's say the Raw is `ABC` it will show `65 66 67`. I tried :

```
self.txt.SetLabelText(" ".join(map(hex,str(pkt[Raw]))))
```

It raises `TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex`

Is there any known way to do it?
I am familiar with `hexdump(pkt)` but it prints the hexdump and also the conversion to string and also doesn't return it..

Comment: Try converting from raw to an integer, or even raw to string to integer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669374/convert-string-to-hex-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
class XStrField(StrField):
   def i2repr(self, pkt, x):
        return ' '.join(b.encode('hex') for b in x)

class MyRaw(Packet):
   fields_desc = [ XStrField("data", None) ]

conf.raw_layer = MyRaw
```